# Why cant I install elementary os?

Tags: system-installation, boot, system, install

I wanted to download and install Elementary Os, so I read the instructions carefully and watched additional tutorials. So far everything has worked out great. However, when I boot the installer from my USB stick, I first come to the start menu where it says that the installer starts in 10 seconds. Then I get a black picture and then this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTuxz.jpg

Do you know how I can fix the problem?

System:
Ryzen 5 2600
RTX 2060
16GB DDR4
Windows 10

I'm looking forward to your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the image is a nightmare. Prepare bootable usb stick using newest elementary OS iso and balena etcher program instead of Rufus or any other software.